# Similar diminutive name construction in Turkish and Armenian

Tags: historical-linguistics, names, turkish, armenian, diminutive

In Armenian diminutive for personal names are formed by adding 'o' for some short part of the name (I'm intentionally not calling this short form "root" cause it's not necessarily a root), so some examples would be:

- Արթուր → Արթո (Arthur → Artho)
- Բաբկեն → Բաբո (Babken → Babo)
- Զավեն → Զավո  (Zaven → Zavo)
- Լուդվիգ → Լուդո (Ludwig → Ludo)

The thing is the similar form of hypocorism [exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism#Turkish) in Turkish:

- Abdullah → Apo
- İbrahim → İbo
- Mehmet → Memo
- Süleyman → Sülo
- Muzaffer → Muzo

And so on. My question would be: regarding the fact that these two-languages co-existed for centuries in the same geographical area, which one influenced which one on this aspect. Or, may be, it's just a coincidence?

Comment: I think at lot of languages all over the world use the suffix -o to form diminutive names, e.g. Arabic, English, German ....

Comment: @fdb can you be more specific - in German to my knowledge it's more about -i ending, in English -o form is just one one possibilities, not the most productive one actually, as of Arabic - I don't know anything about Arabic to be honest.

Comment: @fdb I cannot think of a single instance of _-o_ forming diminutives of personal names in English. It enjoys a certain amount of productivity with male (but not female) given names, but as something more akin to an augmentative (or sometimes pejorative) than a diminutive. _Kiddo_ is, I suppose, vaguely diminutive-ish, but not a name.

Comment: For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacko

Comment: -o is also used like this in Georgian (eg Mikho), Kurdish and in the Balkan Slavic (eg Haso i Mujo).  The -ik diminutive is also all over the place.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer so it's more of some kind of Sprachbund?

Comment: What you say about vocative is not quite correct.  Actually the -o is often dropped in vocative form.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer I'm a native Armenian speaker and after a bit of thought realized that you are actually right, shame on me, let me correct the question )))

Comment: @shabunc -ik is supposedly IE, happened to end up in Russian, Iranic (incl Kurdish) and Armenian.  Supposedly.  Maybe in Turkish *bebek* too.  About -o, I do not know but seems likely Sprachbund.  Multiple dominutives are used very productively and even combined in Armenian, like in Russian.

Comment: @shabunc Have to make room for the *jan*... :Պ

Comment: @fdb It is not really productive in English though.  In German I would say -i is the best analogy.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: -ō(y) is a very productive suffix for hypocoristica in Middle Persian. The Armenian suffix is quite likely to be borrowed from Middle Iranian.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer It's very productive in Australian English.

Comment: @fdb Sounds likely.  Would not be the only feature preserved in other languages but lost in Modern Persian.

Comment: Also relevant that final -o and -a were foreign to Old Armenian, loans had -j added.

Comment: An exhaustive search should be done, but it is possible that no native Turkish lemma ends in -o.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer That is correct, only words ending with -o is loan words. Even postfixes don't end with o.